# How to add styles to an input element when maxlength is reached?

Tags: html, css

Obviously it is quite trivial to detect if the maxlength in an input element has been reached by using JavaScript.

But I was wondering if there is a way currently, or alternatively in any future standards, to do something along the lines of (psuedo-code example) `input:maxlength` or `input:length=[maxlength]`.

Comment: I don't think there is a psuedo way to do that, and for any future standards you would have to build me a time machine first

Comment: I think it isn't possible. Just using JS.

Comment: I doubt that CSS has anything like this, but HTML does. for example for `<input type=text>` you can do `<input type=text maxlength="10">` which will NOT allow more then 10 characters to be input in the textbox, nor sent by POST request.

Comment: @Bluety OP wants to know if there is a way to check for maxlength on an input using css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not in this decade.  This is a long shot.  But it may leave the door open to what you are asking.

The wording of this section is quite ambiguous. If the current selected input could be in "some way" considered a highlight element and you created a custom pseudo-element for length = maxlength.

"Currently no way to distinguish..." says maybe there will be some changes in what is a highlight element.

It is the Last Line in this section that leaves the door open.

### CSS Pseudo-Elements Module Level 4

**3.1. Selecting Highlighted Content:**

The highlight pseudo-elements represent portions of a document that have been highlighted in **some way.**

::selection
    The ::selection pseudo-element represents the portion of a document that has been highlighted by the user. This also applies, for example, to selected text within an editable text field.

Active vs. inactive selections are often styled differently. **Currently no way to distinguish.**

::spelling-error
    The ::spelling-error pseudo-element represents a portion of text that has been flagged by the user agent as misspelled. 
::grammar-error
    The ::grammar-error pseudo-element represents a portion of text that has been flagged by the user agent as grammatically incorrect.

**Note: A future level of CSS may introduce ways to create custom highlight pseudo-elements**.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, there is no way to detect if an input (text or textarea) has reached its max length in CSS or CSS3. If you really want to check it, you'll need javascript as you said yourself.

As for future plans: I haven't seen anything about something like that on the W3C pages, even though it would be very useful. :)